# Why does CR3 register contents vary, when read each time from a kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, x86-64

i was writing a kernel driver with the aim to dissect the Linux kernel page tables.
I found that, whenever i read the CR3 register,from inside the driver, the **contents of CR3 vary each time its read**!

Why does this happen? S ince the driver executes in kernel mode, CR3 needs to point to the kernel page directory (right?), then why is CR3 changing every time?

If CR3 keeps changing, how would memory accesses by the driver happen correctly, as intended?

Comment: from what i read, the contents of CR3 will be the CR3 of that last 'running' process(linux uses per-process paging structures). So analyzing the variation wouldnt make much sense i guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you are seeing the "pagetable" for the current process. With x86, entering a privilege level lower than 3 does not change the page table. This is why most operating systems reserve sections of the virtual address space for the kernel. The memory in that space is mapped into every process. Memory in the kernel address space can be hidden from user mode code by setting the u/s flag in the page frame to "0". That marks it as "system" memory rather than as user memory.

Changing the page table is usually done after transitioning Kernel mode, which is why kernel memory needs to be part of the process's address space. It wouldn't know where to find it's data structures otherwise. One exception is "systems management mode", which switches address spaces transparently. Howeve this can only occur in response to a "system management interrupt", requires special hardware support from the motherboard, and by design cannot be suppressed by or responded to by the operating system.

Othwise, in protected mode, manipulation of the page table is always done by the OS, *after* transition into Kernel Mode. That is part of why a "mode switch" is faster than a full context switch.

Answer (score 3):

CR3 is the page directory pointer.  It will change every time the address space changes at the very least.  There is no single "kernel" memory space.  In most (all?) memory models the CR3 value you see is going to be specific to the address space context you are in (e.g. which process you are handling a syscall from, etc...).

Comment: suppose i have declared a global char array for my kernel module. Now if CR3 doesnt point to the kernel space directory and instead points to some other location, how would accesses to that array succeed? the accesses do succeed !!

Comment: Why wouldn't the access succeed?  The fact that there's a different top-level page directory in use doesn't mean that it can't point to the same physical address for your variable.

Comment: Are you sure thats whats happening? because that would mean the paging structure for every process will have to include a mapping for all those kernel datas ! this doesnt seem to be  a good idea. This would also restrict the range of addresses a process can use.

Comment: I'm all but certain that's what's happening (note that the lower level page tables can be shared).  You have the rig ready, trace it and find out for yourself.  Isn't that the point here?

Comment: The access succeeds because kernel mode address space is mapped the same way for every process.  User mode address space must change for every process which means that CR3 will change depending on what process is running.